# Expected value - Probability and statistics

Tags: probability

X is a Poisson random variable,

I need to find E(1/(X+1))

Anyone can guide me for this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered posing $Y=1/X$?

Comment: $E[g(x)] = \sum_x g(x) P(X = x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the definition of expectation of a function of a random variable, and the Poisson distribution formula. You get

$$E\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k} e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} $$
This might look difficult, but doing the substitution $t=1+k$ you should get a solvable summation (you are supposed to know the exponential series, of course).